# Looking for a simple RaspberryPi keyboard with USB hub to connect mouse to

Tags: usb-power, peripherals

I have a **RaspberryPi model B with 2 USB** ports and I would like to connect 3 devices:

- Keyboard
- Mouse
- USB Flash Disk

I would like to do this without using extra USB powered hub.

Is there any low-powered USB keyboard and mouse which together use only one USB port (shared wireless dongle for both OR USB hub in the keyboard) and each takes <50mA?

Comment: Joudicek, as with most StackExchange sites, shopping recommendations are explicitly off topic. If you have specific questions about how a specific item may work with an RPi, that would be acceptable. As is the question should be closed.

Comment: shopping recommendations are explicitly off topic

Comment: I have updated the question to be more specific. I'm ideally looking for someone that has already tried this with his Raspberry Pi and can confirm given peripherals work together. I hope this is now according to the forum rules as I don't know where else I can find information like this.

Comment: The problem is not specificity.  The problem is, as stated above and explicitly in the [on/off topics page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), shopping recommendations are off topic.   We do have a sibling [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) where this would be fine.  However: Wireless keyboard/mouse combos are very, very, commonplace and **the keyboard and mouse can't draw power from the pi, *they're wireless*.**  They usually take a few AAA batteries each.   You can pick a pair up anywhere for $10-20 USD.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a single receiver wireless keybord and mouse like dell km113 and use the other port for usb flash disk

Answer (score 0):

The key component in this equation is probably not any of the ones you are mentioning, but rather the power supply.

Using the devices you are talking about is probably no problem, but might not work, depending on the devices, and the network adapter, you are using.

A keyboard and a mouse usually uses about 100 mA each, but that may vary wildly depending on model.

The easiest way, of course, is to try. If you get spurious reboots, then try using a network adapter that can provide more power.